# Java Selenium webdriver code not execute ;Password Field remains Empty

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I try to execute  java webdriver code ,selenium test for login page .I passed input from excel it correctly assign values to username , password .once click login  button -

```
 Till login button submit works perfectly. if once login button clicked.. password field in that page remain empty and login attempt failed i cant sort out the problem.
```

Thank you all Your reply and appreciate

```
package exceltest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class sample {

    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception {
        String [][] data;
        data = excelread();

        String expectedtitle;
        for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++ )
        {

        expectedtitle = login(data[i][0],data[i][1]); 

        System.out.println("page title after login is" + expectedtitle );

        if(expectedtitle.equalsIgnoreCase("homepage Title"))
        {

            System.out.println("PASSED");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("FAILED");

            }

        }
    }







    public static String login(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException {
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

         driver.get("http://localhost/xxx/Default.aspx");

         Thread.sleep(1000);
          //driver.findElement(By.id("LoginUserName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("LoginUserName")).sendKeys(username);
           //driver.findElement(By.id("LoginPassword")).clear();


            driver.findElement(By.id("LoginPassword")).sendKeys(password);
            driver.findElement(By.id("LoginLoginButton")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            String expectedtitle = driver.getTitle();
            return expectedtitle;

          }








    public static  String [][] excelread()throws Exception
     {
         File excel = new File("D:\\Book1.xlsx");
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
         XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
         XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

         int totrow = ws.getLastRowNum()+ 1;
         int totcol = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
         String [][] data = new String[totrow][totcol];

         for (int i = 0 ; i < totrow ; i++) {
             XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
             for (int j=0  ; j < totcol ; j++){
             XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
             String value = cellToString(cell);
             data[i][j] = value;
              System.out.println("The value is  "   + value);



             } 
     }
         return data;
         }


     public static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) {
         int type;
         Object result ;
         type = cell.getCellType();
         switch (type) {
         case 0 :
         result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
         break;
         case 1 :
         result = cell.getStringCellValue();
         break;
         default :
         throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
         }
         return result.toString();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please describe what your problem ist and add all relevant information about the environment. If we cannot reproduce your problem we cannot help you!

Comment: @mschenk74 till login button submit works perfectly. if once login button clicked.. password field in that page remain empty and login attempt failed

Comment: @mschenk74 And also waning: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.                but i dont think it is the reson

Comment: The issue seems related to locators only, not in apache POI... Share your Login part of the HTML Code for the web page...

Comment: @Sankumarsingh No yaar Am 100% sure.its not locator mistake

Comment: @Sankumarsingh till login button submit works perfectly. if once login button clicked.. password field in that page remain empty and login attempt failed And also waning: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. but i dont think it is the reason

Comment: Do the same manually ... it may be the case that the page has a functionality as on submit click, it send the login request to server and clear the password field. And it has nothing to do with log4j.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh yes Your are right thank so much for your reply.. and can you give it as asnswer pls

Comment: Please share the login url.

Comment: @Anirudh Thanks for your reply .. igot answer and posted below

Comment: @Sankumarsingh  is tr any solution to came out from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here... i used webdriver code with java eclipse , automate login for  .net web application.the Default password given in "xxx.aspx.cs" page doesnt execute ..     Reason: Case that the page has a functionality as on submit click, it send the login request to server and clear the password field

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the same locator (class 'By') for clearing the password field and to enter the passsword. Are you sure both locators are correct? Your password filed is empty because you are not selecting the right element. You must select the input tag of your html.

Other remarks. You shouldn't use thread.sleep() to make your test case works, you will have race condition. You should keep a reference to the elements. Calling findElement everytime is useless and will make your test slow.

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("whatever"));
e.clear();
e.sendKeys(...);
```

Comment: locators are perfectly right and also retrieved values..  your code also remains same result as before

Comment: till login button submit works perfectly. if once login button clicked.. password field in that page remain empty and login attempt failed